# Array operations with n-dimensional array using LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Assume we have a jagged array

```
int[][] a = { new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, new[] { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };
```

To get a sum of second row and sum of second column, it can be written both code lines respectively:

```
int rowSum = a[1].Sum();
int colSum = a.Select(row => row[1]).Sum();
```

But if we have definition of 2-dimensional array

```
int[,] a = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };
```

the above-cited code will not work due to compiller errors:

```
Error   1   Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2
Error   2   'int[*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'int[*,*]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So, the question: How to use LINQ methods with n-dimensional arrays, but not jagged ones? And is where a method to convert rectangular array to jagged?

P.S. I tried to find the answer in documentation, but without result.

Comment: Multi dimensional arrays aren't truly (extensively) supported in C# :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) is based on the [IEnumerable<T> Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), i.e. a one-dimensional sequence of values. This means it doesn't mix well with n-dimensional data structures like non-jagged arrays, although it's possible.

You can generate one-dimensional sequence of integers that index into the n-dimensional array:

```
int rowSum = Enumerable.Range(0, a.GetLength(1)).Sum(i => a[1, i]);

int colSum = Enumerable.Range(0, a.GetLength(0)).Sum(i => a[i, 1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

About your question "How to use LINQ methods with n-dimensional arrays":

You can't use most LINQ methods with a n dimensional array, because such an array only implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>` and most of the LINQ extension methods are extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`.

About the other question: See dtb's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To add to dtb's solution, a more general way of iterating over all items of the array would be:

```
int[,] b = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };

var flattenedArray = Enumerable.Range(0, b.GetLength(0))
                     .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(0, b.GetLength(1))
                         .Select(j => new { Row = i, Col = j }));
```

And now:

```
var rowSum2 = flattenedArray.Where(t => t.Row == 1).Sum(t => b[t.Row, t.Col]);
var colSum2 = flattenedArray.Where(t => t.Col == 1).Sum(t => b[t.Row, t.Col]);
```

Of course this is ultra-wasteful as we are creating coordinate tuples even for those items that we will end up filtering out with `Where`, but if you don't know what the selection criteria will be beforehand this is the way to go (or not -- this seems more like an excercise than something you 'd want to do in practice).

I can also imagine how this might be extended for arrays of any rank (not just 2D) using a recursive lambda and something like `Tuple`, but that crosses over into masochism territory.

Answer (score 1):

The 2D array doesn't have any built in way of iterating over a row or column.  It's not too difficult to create your own such method though. See this class for an implementation which gets an enumerable for row and column.

```
public static class LINQTo2DArray
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Row<T>(this T[,] Array, int Row)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            yield return Array[Row, i];
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> Column<T>(this T[,] Array, int Column)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            yield return Array[i, Column];
        }
    }
}
```

You can also flatten the array using`a.Cast<int>()` but you would then loose all the info about columns/rows

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is doing like below

```
 var t = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
 int[][] a = t.Select(x => new int[]{ x.Item1, x.Item2}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest LINQ only approach I can see to do these kinds of row and column operations on a two dimensional array is to define the following lookups:

```
var cols = a
    .OfType<int>()
    .Select((x, n) => new { x, n, })
    .ToLookup(xn => xn.n % a.GetLength(1), xn => xn.x);

var rows = a
    .OfType<int>()
    .Select((x, n) => new { x, n, })
    .ToLookup(xn => xn.n / a.GetLength(1), xn => xn.x);
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
var firstColumnSum = cols[0].Sum();
```

As for n-dimensional, it just gets too painful... Sorry.